# How to change the Font Weight of Legend Title matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set the font weight ( bold or italics ) of the legend box title as shown in the following graph. My research shows that title_fontsize inside plt.legend() would change the font size. But, I couldn't figure out a way to change the font weight.

```
plt.legend(
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1),
    loc="upper left",
    borderaxespad=0.0,
    title="Confidence \n Bands",
    fancybox=True,
    title_fontsize=18

)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html), you can do:

```py
plt.legend(title="Confidence \n Bands", title_fontproperties={'weight':'bold'})
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to use the Latex expression to make it bold.

```
plt.legend(
    bbox_to_anchor=(1.04, 1),
    loc="upper left",
    borderaxespad=0.0,
    title=r"$\bf{Confidence \\ Bands}$",
    fancybox=True,
    title_fontsize=18

)
```

Comment: This is helpful. But, it does not go all the way there since I got the error "Unknown symbol: \n" ...  it seems like the legend title became bold after removing another line symbol.

Comment: A line break in '${}$' is '\\' as it is written in Latex, so it needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the snippet .You can use `$\\bf{TITLE}$` for **`bold`** and `$\\it{TITLE}$` for *`italics`*
[image: Bold and Italics]

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y1 = [2, 3, 4.5]   
y2 = [1, 1.5, 5]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(y1,label = "$\\bf{Blue}$") 
ax.plot(y2,label = "$\\it{Yellow}$")   
ax.legend(
           bbox_to_anchor=(0.2, 0.99),
            borderaxespad=0.0,
            title="Confidence \n Bands",
            fancybox=True) 
plt.show()
```